# MSVC 2008 better timing?

Tags: c++, c, windows, timer, interrupt

The project I'm currently working on uses MSVC 2008, I don't have any choice in this.

The operating system that this is being used on is as recent as Windows 10.  I am trying to introduce more accurate timing into the application, however so far most of the searching I've done online has resulted in a dead end where yes newer versions of MSVC do support more accurate timing but I don't have those.

Is there any way to improve on the resolution of the timing, not only the resolution but the accuracy.

I've used and worked on other operating systems such as QNX where its quite possible to work with Nanosecond accurate timers and this is on much older hardware.

Fudge:  Now I'm thinking of combining the results from two routines, calling:

```
    GetLocalTime
```

To return the bulk of the data, year, month, day, hours, minutes and seconds then using:

```
    QueryPerformanceFrequency
    QueryPerformanceCounter
```

To obtain and calculate the microsecond part and masking out anything larger than a second so I maintain a decimal portion down to microseconds.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @xxbbcc, looks promising, thank you, I will take a look.

Comment: Ok. That's just an API call - doesn't matter what version of of MSVC you're using. (You can use it from any language that supports importhing functions.)

Comment: [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408(v=vs.85).aspx) is the definitive reference for timing on windows.

Comment: @MikeVine, thank you, are there any helper routines for translating these results into year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds ?

Comment: @SPlatten For windows 8+, `GetSystemTimePreciseAsFiletime` then `FileTimeToSystemTime`. For windows 7 and lower its a cluster fudge if you need really accurate time, if you dont mind ~16ms accuracy you can use `GetSystemTimeAsFiletime`. This linked article covers this all.

Comment: @MikeVine You're making some comments I'd upvote if they were answers. Let me know if you post.

Comment: @MikeVine, has anyone written a function that will take the number of microseconds and translated into a time structure that will give me everything I require?

Comment: See edit after label "fudge"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution which I've tested and the results are good:

```
    LARGE_INTEGER liFreq, liNow;
    SYSTEMTIME sstNow;       
    char szMsg[768];
    long lngMicro;
    /*Get high performance frequency and counter*/
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&liFreq);
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&liNow);
    /*Work out elapsed microseconds using frequency*/
    liNow.QuadPart *= 1000000;
    liNow.QuadPart /= liFreq.QuadPart;
    /*Mask out everything >= 1 second */
    lngMicro = liNow.QuadPart % 1000000;
    /*Get the system date and time*/
    GetLocalTime(&sstNow);
    /*Build up formatted debug string including sequence number, line number
     *date and time stamp including microseconds and message detail*/
    sprintf_s(szMsg, sizeof(szMsg)
         ,"%4d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d.%06ld DBG:%-24sL%05uSQ%05uET%16.6f%s%s\n"            
         ,sstNow.wYear, sstNow.wMonth, sstNow.wDay
         ,sstNow.wHour, sstNow.wMinute, sstNow.wSecond
         ,lngMicro, cpszClipped, uintLineNo
         ,suintDbgSeqNo, dblElapsed, sszIndents, cpszFormat);
```

This isn't the entire function but hopefully gives enough information for anyone to see what is happening and how it works, here is a snippet of the log file produced using this technique:

```
    2018-05-16 08:17:52.334189 DBG:FsLonSource.cpp         L01079SQ00011ET        5.334189   CFsLonSource::SubmitCommand(AddressType:Local NI, Mode:0, Selector:0)
    2018-05-16 08:17:52.334449 DBG:NodetalkLONInterface.c  L01862SQ00012ET        5.334449     AdapterSetAddress(DomainId:, SubnetId:1, NodeId:1)
    2018-05-16 08:17:52.334807 DBG:NodetalkLONInterface.c  L01522SQ00013ET        5.334807       AdapterSetAddressInternal(DomainId:, SubnetId:1, NodeId:1)
    2018-05-16 08:17:52.335413 DBG:NodetalkLONInterface.c  L01021SQ00014ET        5.335413         NodeSetAddress(ServiceType: ACKD): ok
    2018-05-16 08:17:52.335603 DBG:NodetalkLONInterface.c  L01055SQ00015ET        5.335603         NodeSetModeState()
    2018-05-16 08:17:52.335783 DBG:NodetalkLONInterface.c  L01064SQ00016ET        5.335783           ServiceType: UNACKD
    2018-05-16 08:17:52.335966 DBG:NodetalkLONInterface.c  L01065SQ00017ET        5.335966           NewMode: ?
    2018-05-16 08:17:52.336124 DBG:NodetalkLONInterface.c  L01071SQ00018ET        5.336124           NewState: Configured, Online
    2018-05-16 08:17:52.339081 DBG:FsLonDispatch.cpp       L00342SQ00019ET        5.339081           CFsLonDispatch::ExecRequest(): S_OK
    2018-05-16 08:17:52.433098 DBG:FsLonDispatch.cpp       L00181SQ00020ET        5.433098         CFsLonDispatch::ExecRequest(request:"<UpdateRest xmln", lTimeout:0, destination:"", correlationId:"")
    2018-05-16 08:17:52.436138 DBG:FsLonDispatch.cpp       L00250SQ00021ET        5.436138           strCCommand: UpdateRest
    2018-05-16 08:17:52.436431 DBG:FsLonDispatch.cpp       L00342SQ00022ET        5.436431           CFsLonDispatch::ExecRequest(): S_OK
    2018-05-16 08:17:52.437184 DBG:FsLonDispatch.cpp       L00181SQ00023ET        5.437184         CFsLonDispatch::ExecRequest(request:"<UpdateRest xmln", lTimeout:0, destination:"", correlationId:"")
    2018-05-16 08:17:52.439981 DBG:FsLonDispatch.cpp       L00250SQ00024ET        5.439981           strCCommand: UpdateRest
    2018-05-16 08:17:52.440331 DBG:FsLonDispatch.cpp       L00342SQ00025ET        5.440331           CFsLonDispatch::ExecRequest(): S_OK
    2018-05-16 08:17:52.440705 DBG:FsLonDispatch.cpp       L00181SQ00026ET        5.440705         CFsLonDispatch::ExecRequest(request:"<UpdateRest xmln", lTimeout:0, destination:"", correlationId:"")
    2018-05-16 08:17:52.443586 DBG:FsLonDispatch.cpp       L00250SQ00027ET        5.443586           strCCommand: UpdateRest
    2018-05-16 08:17:52.443792 DBG:FsLonDispatch.cpp       L00342SQ00028ET        5.443792           CFsLonDispatch::ExecRequest(): S_OK
    2018-05-16 08:17:52.951870 DBG:NodetalkLONInterface.c  L01108SQ00029ET        5.951870         ServiceType: REQUEST
    2018-05-16 08:17:52.955944 DBG:NodetalkLONInterface.c  L01152SQ00030ET        5.955944         NodeSetModeState(): ok
    2018-05-16 08:17:52.956289 DBG:NodetalkLONInterface.c  L01555SQ00031ET        5.956289       AdapterSetAddressInternal(): ok
    2018-05-16 08:17:52.956655 DBG:NodetalkLONInterface.c  L01597SQ00032ET        5.956655     AdapterSetRcvTimer(ServiceType: REQUEST, AddressType: LOCAL)
    2018-05-16 08:17:52.966897 DBG:NodetalkLONInterface.c  L01625SQ00033ET        5.966897       AdapterSetRcvTimer(): ok
    2018-05-16 08:17:52.967216 DBG:NodetalkLONInterface.c  L01878SQ00034ET        5.967216     AdapterSetAddress(): ok
    2018-05-16 08:17:52.967531 DBG:FsLonSource.cpp         L01174SQ00035ET        5.967531   CFsLonSource::SubmitCommand(): ok
```

Comment: you can't take the seconds and the microseconds from a different source. They are not necessarily synchronized or in phase.

Comment: Synchronisation doesn’t matter it’s just to give a chronological reference and it works

Comment: I wonder how it would look at the transition to the next second....(this is missing in the output shown here)